# docker load from (large) tar.gz fails

Tags: docker

I have a gigantic tar file that contains a large number of docker images.  The file is about 7GB compressed, and 18GB uncompressed, and contains 65 .docker files.

```
[root@hostname folder]# docker load --input dockerImages.tgz
open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-944025724/repositories: no such file or directory
```

If I unpack the tar on the host filesystem and execute "docker load" on each individual .docker file one at a time, they all load properly.  But I've been asked not to do that - I'm told I should be able to just load the tar (.tgz) file directly, and all the .docker images it contains should be loaded.

I have also tried

- with an uncompressed file ("docker load --input dockerImages.tar");
- with a much smaller tgz file containing only 2-10 .docker files;
- using "docker image load --input dockerImages.tgz (is that the same thing?);
- using input redirection instead of --input ("docker load < dockerImages.tgz")

All with the same error message result (the docker-import-folder number changes each time I run the command - seems normal.)  /var/lib/docker/tmp is empty on my host, and 'docker ps' shows nothing running.

I successfully executed a 'docker login --username userid --password -password localhost:5000' prior to attempting these commands.

I can't tell if docker is unpacking the tar and running out of space on the underlying file system, or if the tar is something more than just a collection of .docker files - does it need a some sort of manifest or other file in order to succeed and maybe it is not constructed properly.  All of the docker files are at the root of the tar file - there are no root folders.

I don't see a verbose or debug option to docker (is that right?); I have tried executing the command in the background, and I don't see any disks filling up (watching "df -h"), but based on something I read - that the images are loaded inside a container - perhaps a container disk is filling up?  Is a manifest required?  Does the tar have to be constructed by appending successive "docker save" command outputs?

I realize docker is old technology, but it's new to me.  Any insights would be appreciated.

OS: RHEL 7.7 x86_64  Docker version: Client 19.03.5 Community  Server 19.03.5 Community

Comment: Watching it, I am seeing that /var/lib/docker/tmp gets a docker-import-###### folder which is being populated with the contents of the tar file.  The tar file does not have a repositories file.  Does it need one?  The /var disk is not being filled up.

Comment: How are you originally producing the tar file?  Is it a single `docker save` command, or something else?

Comment: I believe the .docker files are created by docker save.  The tar file is simply an archive of dozens of .docker files.  "tar cfz dockerImages.tgz *.docker"

Comment: Then yeah, you'll probably have to unpack that tar-file-of-tar-files first.  The image tar file has [a specific format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ImageGet) and the error message you're getting sounds like the combined tar-file-of-tar-files isn't in that format.

Comment: Yes, it appears the tar file fed to 'docker load' is not simply a collection of .docker files.  I ran 'docker save' on multiple images and the result was a tar archive with a repository but no docker files - lots of other stuff unfamiliar to me.  So it appears I was following a bad lead.  The link was helpful; thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise is invalid.  A tar file fed to "docker load" is not simply a collection of .docker files each produced by "docker save".  While there may be other ways, a tar file produced by naming multiple images in a "docker save" command is one way to produce a tar file that contains multiple docker images; its content will not be multiple .docker files.